# How to set layout and footer format with scrletter?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, letters, scrletter

Consider the following minimal example with a letter (scrletter) inside a scrartcl:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrletter}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\KOMAoptions{backaddress=off,foldmarks=off}


\begin{document}

\date{\today}
\setkomavar{fromname}{From}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Strasse XX\\PLZ Ort}
\setkomavar{signature}{Robert}

\setkomavar{subject}{Betreff}

\begin{letter}[fontsize=12pt]{To\\Strasse XX\\PLZ Ort}

\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren}

Letter page 1

\pagebreak

Letter page 2

\closing{Freundliche Grüsse}
\end{letter}

Test

\end{document}
```

Two questions:

- Where do I specify the address layout (like `SN`, `DIN`, `SNleft`, ...)?
- I now have three different page numberings (first page: none, second page: 'Seite 2', third page: '3'). How can I achieve a consistent page numbering like this: '1', '2', '3'?

Comment: `scrletter` is deprecated. You should be using `scrlttr2`. See the KOMAdoc documentation for more details on usage. Not sure if that will solve your problems.

Comment: @DonHosek *Package* `scrletter` is part of the current KOMA-Script bundle. It is *not* deprecated and can be used with the KOMA-Script classes `scrartcl`, `scrreprt` and `scrbook`. `scrlttr2` is a class.

Comment: The reason I'm using scrletter is because I can use it as an environment inside another class (scrartcl in this case).

Comment: Oops, I was confusing it with `scrlettr`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letter class option `DIN` is loaded by default. If you want to load an other letter class option use `\LoadLetterOption` or if you want to load a list of `lco` files use `\LoadLetterOptions`. Note that you have to load `scrletter` before you use `\LoadLetterOption` or `\LoadLetterOptions`.

If the output of the page number should be the same in the letter use

```
\let\letterpagemark\pagemark
```

Note that the first letter page has a special layout. It uses page style `empty`. If the page number should be in the footer of the first letter page you can use

```
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\centering\pagemark}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrletter}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed with outdated TeX distributions
\LoadLetterOption{SN}% <- added
\KOMAoptions{backaddress=off,foldmarks=off}
\let\letterpagemark\pagemark% <- added
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\centering\pagemark}% <- added

\setkomavar{fromname}{From}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Strasse XX\\PLZ Ort}
\setkomavar{signature}{Robert}
\setkomavar{subject}{Betreff}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}[fontsize=12pt]{To\\Strasse XX\\PLZ Ort}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren}
Letter page 1
\clearpage

Letter page 2
\closing{Freundliche Grüsse}
\end{letter}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the quick response!